# Sync failed with Gradle in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle

I' m writing my first Android app. I' ve installed successfully Android Studio. I' ve create a nw project, SDK 4.2, empty activity. I' m trying to make/build/run the app before starting to edit it, but i got this error:

> Error:Cause: org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory cannot be cast to ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext
>   Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
>     Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
>     Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

It appears on my win7 PC x64, with 1.8 jdk. I' ve tried on a VM with winXP and it worked at first launch. What can I do?

Comment: did you try to invalidate cache and retry building. Available under Android Studio -> `Invalidate Caches And Restart`

Comment: I tried it, but it didn' t work

Comment: try killing all java process as said in the error message. If not solved post your build.gradle

Comment: it didn't worked. here it is:
> // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing same problem.

[I followed this google group link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/liftweb/QB_bMgsQBwU)

Then I come to know that I have some other version of slf4j.jar file. I just removed it from /jdk/jre/ext/ folder and it worked for me.

I think this will be useful